# Preview is unscriptable with annotation toolbar open on Mountain Lion

Tags: applescript, osx-mountain-lion, preview

Trying to write a UI script for Preview to play with annotations but it seems that opening the annotations toolbar breaks scripting. I noticed that any customised hotkeys also stop working once the annotations toolbar is open.

This can be replicated by the following applescript run with the toolbar open then again when closed:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Preview"
        tell front window
            return every UI element
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Am I doing something wrong here or is Preview just broken?

Cheers

Comment: Do you mean the "edit toolbar"? It does have annotations stuff on it. I do not have any trouble with your script with or without that toolbar open.

Comment: Yep, Edit toolbar is what I mean. The script spits out a blank result when I run it with the Edit toolbar open. Does yours show results in both cases?

Comment: Yes, I get results in either case.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working using the instructions posted by Michael Tsai in this thread - [Is OSX Lion Preview application scriptable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474657/is-osx-lion-preview-application-scriptable).

The direct link to the posted article is http://c-command.com/blog/2009/12/28/capture-from-preview/